# How will I add a dynamic value and character on a PHP string?

Tags: php

I have login page where users are categorized by usergroup from database when they login

| **Username** | **Usergroup** |
|--- Admin ---| -----1 --------|
|--- John ----    | -----2-------- |
|--- Mary ----    | -----3-------- |

I created a table on mysql that has tablenames like :  View_1 , View_2 , View_3.

What i would like to know is how will i be able to add the characters to my condition to refer in the database column where the number is equivalent on the usergroup of the username who logged in.

```
$usergroup = $_SESSION['data']['usergroup'];
$newvalue = ['View_+ $usergroup']; 

if($configuration_data['$newvalue'] == 0) {
  header("Location: forbidden.php"); 
}
```

Comment: Do `$newvalue = ["View_{$usergroup}"]; `  and `$configuration_data[$newvalue]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with your syntax, by doing `$newvalue = ['View_+ $usergroup'];` you're creating a new array with in it the string *'View_+ $usergroup'*. *(I assume that your `$configuration_data` variable is of the form `['View_1' => 0, 'View_2' => 1, 'View_3' => 0]`...)*

To use **[Variables Parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)** in PHP, you must use double quotes :

```
$usergroup = $_SESSION['data']['usergroup'];

$newvalue = "View_$usergroup"; 
// OR $newvalue = "View_${usergroup}"
// OR $newvalue = "View_".$usergroup; 

if ($configuration_data[$newvalue] == 0) {
  header("Location: forbidden.php");
}
```